# Samsung IR codes checksum

Tags: arduino, checksum, infrared

I had a long time decoding IR codes with optimum's [Ken Shirriff](http://www.arcfn.com/2009/08/multi-protocol-infrared-remote-library.html) Arduino Library. I modified the code a bit so that I was able to dump a Samsung air conditioner (MH026FB) 56-bit signals.

The results of my work is located in Google Docs document *[Samsung MH026FB AirCon IR Codes Dump](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Aupzmp8AqC8JdGtNOXhUc0R0WC1hbVdRa0p3aDVxdFE#gid=0)*.

It is a spreasheet with all dumped values and the interpretation of results. AFAIK, air conditioner unit sends out two or three "bursts" of 56 bit data, depending on command. I was able to decode bits properly, figuring out where air conditioner temperature, fan, function and other options are located.

The problem I have is related to the **checksum**. In all those 7-byte codes, the **second one** is computed somehow from the latter 5 bytes, for example:

```
BF B2 0F FF FF FF F0   (lead-in code)
7F B8 8A 71 F6 4F F0   (auto mode - 25 degrees)
7F B2 80 71 7A 4F F0   (auto mode - 26 degrees)
7F B4 80 71 FA 7D F0   (heat mode - 26 degrees - fan auto)
```

Since I re-create the IR codes at runtime, I need to be able to **compute checksum** for these codes.

I tried with many standard checksum algorithms, none of them gave meaningful results. The checksum seems to be related to number of zeroes in the rest of code (bytes from 3 to 7), but I really can't figure it how.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: I know the question is a bit old, but since the 56-bit Samsung decoder is not in Sherriff's library, if the OP still has his work, could he please upload it somewhere (github) or, better, create a pull request into Shirriff's repository?

Comment: the code has been embedded long ago inside Souliss open-source framework. You may look there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ken Shirriff sorted this out. Algorithm is as follow:

1. **Count the number of 1 bits** in all the bytes except #2 (checksum)
2. Compute **count mod 15**. If the value is 0, use 15 instead.
3. Take the value from 2, **flip** the 4 bits, and **reverse** the 4 bits.
4. The checksum is **Bn** where n is the value from the previous step.

Congraturations to him for his smartness and sharpness.

Answer (score 1):

When bit order in **`bytes/packets`** and **0/1** are interpreted properly (from the algorithm it appears that both are reversed), the algorithm would be just **`sum of 0 bits modulo 15`**.

Answer (score 1):

It is nearly correct.
Count the 0's / 1's (You can call them what you like, but it is the short signals).
Do not count 2. byte and first/last bit of 3.byte (depending if you are seeing it as big or little indian).
Take the result and -30 (29-30 = 15, only looking af 4 bits!)
Reverse result
Checksum = 0x4 "reverse resultesult", if short signals = 0, and 0xB "reverse resultesult" if long signal = 0.

Answer (score 0):

i used Ken's method but mod 15 didnt work for me.

Count the number of 1 bits in all the bytes except #2 (checksum)
Compute count mod 17. if value is 16, use first byte of mode result(0).
Take the value , flip the 4 bits.
The checksum is 0xn9 where n is the value from the previous step.